# How to use wildcards in between and SQL clause?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to write a SQL.

```
select * from table where c between c1 and c2
```

The c1 and c2 are user input value . And if user did not enter value for them, it will return all records. How to do that? I tried

```
select * from table where c between '%' and '%'
```

And it doesn't return anything. Thx.

Comment: What is the datatype of `c` column?

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov. its varchar2(25).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most common way to what you want is to use `OR`, for example:

```sql
select * from table where c between c1 and c2 or (:c1 is null and :c2 is null)
```

(what do you want to get if only one of c1 or c2 is null?)

Such approach allows oracle optimizer (CBO) to apply or-expand transformation. Ie, cbo can choose better execution plan for both variants (for example index range scan in case of small range c1-c2 and full table scan for nulls).

Another option is to use `nvl()` (or ansi complient `coalesce`), for example for binary_float or binary_double:

```sql
select * from table where c between nvl(:c1, 1f/0) and nvl(:c2, -1f/0)
```

But I wouldn't suggest it since it you may get problems with correct cardinality estimation. (bad plans)

PS. 1f/0 and -1f/0 are just positive and negative infinity.

Comment: Where were you all these months? Missed your answers, enjoy reading them.

Comment: @Littlefoot thanks a lot for such kind words! :) hardworkinng :( but I also answer on Oracle-L freelists, telegram groups and russian sql.ru forum :)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `or`, but not with `between`:

```
select *
from table
where (c >= :c1 or :c1 is null) and
      (c <= :c2 or :c2 is null)
```

However, this may not be optimal for the optimizer.  If you are constructing this in an application, you might want conditional logic that creates one of the following `where` clauses:

```
where c >= :c1
where c <= :c2
where c >= :c1 and c <= :c2
```